# Why is the same module listed three times at metacpan.org?

Tags: perl, metacpan

Searching for `Devel::Peek` at [metacpan.org](https://metacpan.org/) gives the following screen shot:

---

[image]

---

Why is the module listed three times? (It looks a little bit strange, and could easily confuse the user..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oddly enough, there's one missing. The following are Devel::Peek's official distributions:

- [`perl`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/perl)
- [`Devel-Peek`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Devel-Peek)

These two distributions are [returned](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=Devel%3A%3APeek&mode=all) when searching [search.cpan.org](http://search.cpan.org/), and the only two distributions returned when searching search.cpan.org.

Being part of the `perl` distribution and part of its own distribution is called being a "dual-lifed" module. It allows the module to be bundled with Perl without having to upgrade Perl to upgrade the module.

I don't know why meta::cpan doesn't pick up the official distribution, and I don't know why it doesn't flag the other distributions as unofficial. You could alert the site's maintainers of the problem.

Conversely, I don't know why search.cpan.org doesn't return `CookBookA` and `CookBookB`, and why it doesn't flag theses other distributions as unofficial when one goes to it directly. I think it has to do with the fact that Devel::Peek is only present as a documentation file (.pod) —not a module (.pm)— in them.

Comment: hum? You didn't mention either of the problems. (You simply complain that it listed valid matches! That's not a bug.) Added the actual issues as a comment.